# SoftLayer verifyOrder API returned Internal error

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Following the example in
    https://gist.github.com/bmpotter/27913e92e9ff7b6b0c54
we tried to use the SoftLayer API to order a Bare Metal machine.

Our "verifyOrder" request i.e. ( https://$SLUSERNAME:$SLAPIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder.json ) using the following json

{
"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server", 
"quantity":1,
"hardware":[{"hostname":"userBM3", "domain":"cloud.com", "primaryBackendNetworkComponent":{"networkVlan":{"id":1050255, "primarySubnetId":1223965}}}],
"location":"dal09", 
"useHourlyPricing":false, 
"packageId":251,
"prices":[{"id":50659}, {"id":49447}, {"id":31154}, {"id":40148}, {"id":35963}, {"id":25014}, {"id":34807}, {"id":27023}, {"id":32627}, {"id":32500}, {"id":33483}, {"id":35310}, {"id":156765}, {"id":156765}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":49841}, {"id":50223}, {"id":141945}],
"storageGroups":[{"arrayTypeId":2, "hardDrives":[0, 1]},{"arrayTypeId":2, "hardDrives":[2, 3]}, {"arrayTypeId":9, "hardDrives":[4]}, {"arrayTypeId":9, "hardDrives":[5]}, {"arrayTypeId":9, "hardDrives":[6]}, {"arrayTypeId":9, "hardDrives":[7]}, {"arrayTypeId":9, "hardDrives":[8]}, {"arrayTypeId":9, "hardDrives":[9]}, {"arrayTypeId":9, "hardDrives":[10]}, {"arrayTypeId":9, "hardDrives":[11]}]

}

resulted in the following response

{"error":"An internal system error has occurred.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_InternalError"}

We verified that all the price ids are valid and not able to figure out what is causing the internal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following REST request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server",
         "quantity":1,
         "hardware":[  
            {  
               "hostname":"userBM3",
               "domain":"cloud.com",
               "primaryBackendNetworkComponent":{  
                  "networkVlan":{  
                     "id":1050255,
                     "primarySubnetId":1223965
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "location":"DALLAS09",
         "useHourlyPricing":false,
         "packageId":251,
         "prices":[  
            {  
               "id":50659
            },
            {  
               "id":49447
            },
            {  
               "id":31154
            },
            {  
               "id":40148
            },
            {  
               "id":35963
            },
            {  
               "id":25014
            },
            {  
               "id":34807
            },
            {  
               "id":27023
            },
            {  
               "id":32627
            },
            {  
               "id":32500
            },
            {  
               "id":33483
            },
            {  
               "id":35310
            },
            {  
               "id":156765
            },
            {  
               "id":156765
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":49841
            },
            {  
               "id":50223
            },
            {  
               "id":141945
            }
         ],
         "storageGroups":[  
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":2,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  0,
                  1
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":2,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  2,
                  3
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":9,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  4
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":9,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  5
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":9,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  6
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":9,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  7
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":9,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  8
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":9,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  9
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":9,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  10
               ]
            },
            {  
               "arrayTypeId":9,
               "hardDrives":[  
                  11
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

A quick view, there exist conflict between prices and Dallas09 location, see this article for more information please: [Location-based Pricing and You](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you)

> Updated

The **156765** price (description: 2.00 TB SATA) It's not a a valid price for **Dallas 9**

If you want to order the same item in Dallas 9, change **49821** instead of **156765**

> Price: **49821** which is a standard price (description: 2.00 TB).

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices)

Comment: Ths.  we did change to use 49821 yesterday and confirmed that it works.   What change corrected the "Internal Error problem" and any pointers on how to debug that would be very helpful?  thx

Comment: I added: **"parameters":[ {** in your template. See this information to get more information about using REST with SoftLayer API: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest